# php print all filenames in context of calling scripts

Tags: php

Folks,
I am trying to echo out a string of all files that recursively called in a context to the final script
for example

- index.php includes c.php
- c.php includes b.php
- b.php includes a.php
- a.php prints out "index.php_c.php_b.php_a.php"

I am able to collect parent file and current file, but all middle files are not being captured, unless I store the names in a local variable and pass that along to the final destination.

Is there a way to capture this context?

something like following

```
// a.php
<?php
function callme()
{
$localfile = basename(__FILE__);
$parentfile = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
//$self = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
//echo $self;
//echo $b.$callfile;
echo $parentfile."_".$localfile;
}
?>

//b.php
<?php
include('a.php');
callme();
?>

// c.php
<?php
include('b.php');
?>

// index.php
<?php
include('c.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`get_included_files`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) function. It will give you an array containing the names of the files that were included so far.

```
// a.php:
<?php
include('b.php');
var_dump(get_included_files());

==========

//b.php:
<?php
include('c.php');

==========

//c.php:
<?php
// do nothing
```

Output will be:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => string 'a.php' (length=5)
    1 => string 'b.php' (length=5)
    2 => string 'c.php' (length=5)
```

> Note that the function works the same if you will put it inside one of the included files. You can put the function inside `c.php` (and not inside `a.php`) and the output will not change.

Comment: that works, but now the problem is if there are 10 files included in any one of the files, it will print them all,

Comment: Thats correct, it will give you all files that you included all-over the run-time of your code.